# Another Rebus! Guess the Common Theme and Solve!

Tags: rebus, knowledge

I thought this would be a fun idea for a rebus, so I thought I would share! Some are easier than others, but D is definitely the hardest!

[image]

Shoutout to [Quantumtwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530/quantumtwinkie) for helping with some of the clue ideas!

Comment: Since the solution is spread across 4 answers, maybe a community answer is the way to go?

Comment: @Phylyp; I think you should get it honestly.  You figured out the pattern.

Comment: Yes, good job everybody! Credit goes to: CarlLondahl, APrough. Phylyp, and thecoder16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Partial answer:

C:

> [Eye of the Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_the_Tiger)

F:

> [Jailhouse Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jailhouse_Rock_(song))

Common theme:

> Popular songs

---

For completeness' sake here are the answers for the other rebuses, as provided by other users (please do upvote their answers!):

A (answered by [thecoder16](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61507/33080)):

> Heart and Soul(Seoul) Fits the song theme

B (answered by [APrough](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61509/33080))

> Back in Black

D (answered by [APrough](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61509/33080))

> Gangnam Style (gang is a group of elk, nam is whited out, and Harry Style(s))

E (answered by [Carl Löndahl](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61510/33080))

> Amazing Grace (amazon gray ice)

Comment: You are correct so far! :)

Answer (score 7):

A:

> Heart and Soul(Seoul) Fits the song theme

Comment: This is correct! :)

Answer (score 6):

E:

> Amazing Grace (amazon gray ice)

Comment: This is correct! :)

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer

B:

> Back in Black

D:

> Gangnam Style (gang is a group of elk, nam is whited out, and Harry Style(s)

Comment: Very good, I did not know if anybody would guess that one! :D

Comment: Very good, that's all of them now! @APrough